# Is there a way to setup scoket along with http for multitenant nestjs app

Tags: sockets, nestjs, database-connection, multi-tenant

In nestjs app every http request is intercepted and given a tenant connection through connectionFactory thats defined in tenantModule but the same can't be done on socket connection because the scope property could be only extended for http requests in nestjs is there a work around for sockets?

No other scope properties provided by nestjs seems to intercept socket

attached code of my tenantModule

```
const connectionFactory = {
  provide: TENANT_CONTEXT,
  inject: [REQUEST, DataSource],
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
  useFactory: async (request, dataSource: DataSource) => {
    //code to get tenant connection
  }
};
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [connectionFactory],
  exports: [connectionFactory],

})
export class TenantModule { }
```